# How to derive a function with one variable that is a list?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have a function $f(x_{i})_{t} = \frac{x_{i}}{min(x)}(t)$, where

- x is a list of objects and $x_{i}$ is each object on this list.
- $t$ is the time that I am evaluating the function.
- $min(x)$ is the minimal value of the list of objects in $x$.

The table below exemplifies the behavior of my function. Each chunk of lines is a new time $t$ that was passed.

```
+----+----+--------+-------------+
| t  | x  | min(x) | f(x_{i})_{t}|
+----+----+--------+-------------+
| 1  | 80 |   20   | 80/20 = 4   |
|    | 20 |   20   | 20/20 = 1   |
+----+----+--------+-------------+
|    | 80 |   20   | 80/20 = 4   |
| 2  | 20 |   20   | 20/20 = 1   |
|    | 50 |   20   | 50/20 = 2.5 |
+----+----+--------+-------------+
|    | 80 |   20   | 80/20 = 4   |
| 3  | 20 |   20   | 20/20 = 1   |
|    | 50 |   20   | 50/20 = 2.5 |
|    |200 |   20   |200/20 = 10  |
+----+----+--------+-------------+
|    |500 |   20   |500/20 = 25  |
| 4  | 20 |   20   | 20/20 = 1   |
|    |700 |   20   |700/20 = 35  |
|    |200 |   20   |200/20 = 10  |
+----+----+--------+-------------+
```

I want to derive it w.r.t. the time $t$. I am doing some assumptions that I am not sure if it is correct. For instance:

- I have only one variable that is $x$. The $min(x)$ is going to behave
  as a constant. Right?
- If the denominator is a constant when I derive it will be zero, and anything divided by zero is infinity.

I guess I am trying to derive it in the wrong way. Or maybe the function has to be modeled in another way. Can someone clarify it to me?

Comment: I don't see the relation to time, in the table. How do $x_i$ and time relate to each other? If you want to differentiate something with respect to time, you should know something about the timely values, right?

Comment: I added the column of time. But maybe I am wrong in this assumption as well? I mean, the time is just the frequency that I am applying the function. At time 5 could be another totally different values for $x$. But the linearity of the function is in the relation of all values of the list $x$ when I apply the function. Could I make myself understadable?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to actually do. For example, the value $x_2$ is always equal to $20$, so it would seem like it's "derivative" is zero. Is the length of the list increasing at every time step?

Comment: the length of the list is variable as well. It can increase or decrease.

Comment: So let's take a look at $x_1$, for example. It's values, as "time" grows, are
$$
80, 80, 80, 500
$$
So why did it jump to $500$, suddenly?

Comment: there is no patter on it and I am not modeling it with the assumption that has to be a pattern, linear or not.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing the following function:

$f(x(t)) = x(t)/min(x(t)), x \in R^n$

$t \to x(t) \to f(x(t)), R \to R^n \to R^n$

It means, at each time step you provide the first law, mapping the time step to a vector from an n-dimensional vector space. Then you divide each element of the vector (of the "list") by the minimum of them all and you have your final value.

unfortunately, min() is not a differentiable function in $R^n$ and also the action of dividing each component of the vector by a quantity that can be equal to zero is a potential source of troubles. However, there always will be a subset of $R^n$ in which your function will behave well enough to be differentiable.

Once you determine the subset in which you can profitably use and derive your function, the derivative itself is rather simple. Your function in such a nice subset of $R^n$ would have the expression [ (x<sub>1</sub>+d<sub>1</sub>)/(x<sub>min</sub>+d<sub>min</sub>), (x<sub>2</sub>+d<sub>2</sub>)/(x<sub>min</sub>+d<sub>min</sub>), .. ,1, ...] where x<sub>1</sub>,..,x<sub>min</sub>,.. are the coordinates of the vector and d<sub>1</sub>,d<sub>2</sub> are perturbation coefficients that are supposed to be small.

Derive with respect to the d_i and you are done. For example with $R^2$, near (2,1) your function looks like [(2+d1)/(1+d2),1]. The derivative of f(d1,d2) with respect to d12 is simply [1/(1+d2),0]. Mind that if for instance d2 is allowed to grow big enough to change the argument of the minimum in the vector, the differentiability of the function does not hold anymore and your formulas would not be consistent with the mathematical representation derivation.

Comment: what do you define to be $R^n$?

Comment: why did you add a perturbation coefficients $d_1$ and $d_2$?

Comment: I didn't understand anything in the last paragraph. Could you please explain piecewise the last paragraph?